# Get class members dynamically while reading list member value

Tags: c#, dynamic-list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class student
    {
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string age {get;set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<student> st = new List<student>();
        student s = new student();
        s.name = "Aarif";
        s.age = "25";
        st.Add(s);

        object dyn = "name";

        string Name = st[0].name;
            //I want to read name member dynamically here in below line so help me please
            string Name1 = st[0].dyn;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello "+ Name1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise following .NET naming conventions, e.g. `Student`, `Name` and `Age` for the type and properties, then `name` and `name1` for the local variables.